# Retain Android Activity State When Go To Detail From List ActivityList.java--->ActivityDetail.java -->Back to ActivityList.java

Tags: android

I am facing strange issue. I have one List which i am binding on ActivityList.java page with the use of one adapter. In adapter on the click of ViewButton i am calling ActivityDetail.java . But when press back button and comes to ActivityList.java all my variables and activity state is lost. i Want to retain the same when i come back from ActivityDetail.java.

ActivityList.java--->

_lstCity;

I am getting city list from database and assigning it to _lstCity. When i came back from activityDetail.java i want to use the same variable so that i don't need to go to database again n again.

A big Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Better post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can save any data you dont wanna loss on `onSaveInstanceState` method then respore it on `onRestoreInstanceState`.

And yes, you better post your code.

Comment: I tried doing the same but onRestoreInstanceState never got called